# Error using instrumentation class with -javaagent on play framework 2.1.0-java

Tags: java, playframework, instrumentation, playframework-2.1, javaagents

I've been using an instrumentation class "SizeOfAgent" to calculate memory requirements on my play 2.0.4 environment.
In order to do that I have put "-javaagent:lib\sizeof.jar" on the java command line in the file framework\build.bat 
This jar file has a manifest file with the pre main class configuration to the sizeof.agent.SizeOfAgent
This is working fine and I've been using the fullSizeOf method on some components of my application.

After upgrading to the play 2.1.0 version, this feature is not working anymore.
I'm receiving the error:
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception [IllegalStateException: Can not access instrumentation environment.
Please check if jar file containing SizeOfAgent class is
specified in the java's "-javaagent" command line argument.]

This error is generated because the "static Instrumentation inst" is returning null:

```
    public static long sizeOf(Object o, boolean print) {
            if(inst == null) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Can not access instrumentation environment.\n" +
                                    "Please check if jar file containing SizeOfAgent class is \n" +
                                    "specified in the java's \"-javaagent\" command line argument.");
            }
            if (print) {
                System.out.println(o.getClass().getName() + " : " + inst.getObjectSize(o));
            }
            return inst.getObjectSize(o);
    }
```

Does anyone tried to use an instrumentation class with play 2.1.0?